# How can I drop a table in a database if another table exists?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to drop a table in a database if another table exists.

I made a backup of a table using this query:

```
ALTER TABLE AppProfile RENAME TO AppProfile_backup
```

Now I'd like to restore the backup table and delete AppProfile via something like:

```
DROP TABLE AppProfile IF EXISTS TABLE AppProfile_backup
(ALTER TABLE AppProfile_backup RENAME TO AppProfile) IF NOT EXISTS AppProfile
```

However, I get syntax errors for both lines, near the "IF" token.

For background about this problem, I'm using the SQLiteOpenHelper class in Android. You can execute raw SQL in that environment by making the call [db_handler_instance].getWritableDatabase().execSQL("random query");

Comment: Why do the DROP and CREATE at all? TRUNCATE and then INSERT would be a much better approach.

Comment: @Declan_K: That wouldn't work if the table structure of `AppProfile` has to be changed; in particular, if columns have to be deleted. Adding and checking for columns is possible (using `pragma table_info(<table_name>)`). So it depends ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

What about doing this in Java? You can query the data dictionary ...

```java
String sql = "SELECT 1 "
           + "  FROM sqlite_master  " 
           + " WHERE type = 'table' "
           + "   AND name = 'AppProfile_backup'";

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

... and drop the table, if the backup table is existing:

```java
if (cursor.moveToNext())
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE AppProfile;");
else
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE ...");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the table existence by looking for it in the definition of your database
something like the following should do the trick

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TheSchema' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable'))
```

Comment: This is not valid SQLite syntax either; there is no `IF`.